# .NET 4.5 SessionAuthenticationModule - Issue with "validFrom"

Tags: .net-4.5, wif, acs

I'm using SWT in Windows Azure ACS and custom SwtHandler is used in Relying Party applicaiton to handle incoming SWT token. While it re-creates the SWT token at relying party, I get an error with creation of SessionSecurityToken related to value of validFrom attribute.

I've tried out following values for ValidFrom, but didn't fix the problem.

1. DateTime SwtBaseTime = new DateTime( 1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
2. DateTime.UtcNow
3. DateTime.MinValue
   Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
   Parameter name: validFrom

[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: validFrom]

System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityToken..ctor(ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal, UniqueId contextId, String id, String context, Byte[] key, String endpointId, Nullable`1 validFrom, Nullable`1 validTo, UniqueId keyGeneration, Nullable`1 keyEffectiveTime, Nullable`1 keyExpirationTime, SctAuthorizationPolicy sctAuthorizationPolicy, Uri securityContextSecurityTokenWrapperSecureConversationVersion) +1009610
   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityToken..ctor(ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal, UniqueId contextId, String context, String endpointId, Nullable`1 validFrom, Nullable`1 validTo, SymmetricSecurityKey key) +317
   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.CreateSessionSecurityToken(ClaimsPrincipal principal, String context, String endpointId, DateTime validFrom, DateTime validTo) +306
   System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule.CreateSessionSecurityToken(ClaimsPrincipal principal, String context, DateTime validFrom, DateTime validTo, Boolean isPersistent) +313
   System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SignInWithResponseMessage(HttpRequestBase request) +1079
   System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs args) +123924
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +80
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +165

Comment: As per MSDN, the ArgumentOutOfRange occurs when validFom is greater than or equal to validTo. But I don't see this case while comparing the values.

Comment: Changing DateTime SwtBaseTime = new DateTime( 1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ) to
DateTime SwtBaseTime = new DateTime( 1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc ) fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem recreating the session security token while trying to implement sliding expiration for the SessionAuthenticationModule.

```
protected void SessionAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenReceived(object sender, SessionSecurityTokenReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
    DateTime validFrom = e.SessionToken.ValidFrom;
    DateTime validTo = e.SessionToken.ValidTo;
    TimeSpan sessionLifetime = validTo.Subtract(e.SessionToken.ValidFrom);

    bool sessionTimeHasExpired = now > validTo;
    bool sessionTimeIsHalfExpired = now > validFrom.AddMinutes(sessionLifetime.TotalMinutes / 2);

    // http://www.michael-mckenna.com/Blog/2013/2/the-problem-with-absolute-token-expiration-in-windows-identity-foundation-wif
    if (!sessionTimeHasExpired && sessionTimeIsHalfExpired)
    {
        // If the session has not expired but the session lifetime is already half spent, reissue the cookie. 
        e.SessionToken = (sender as SessionAuthenticationModule).CreateSessionSecurityToken(e.SessionToken.ClaimsPrincipal, e.SessionToken.Context,
        now, now.AddMinutes(sessionLifetime.TotalMinutes), e.SessionToken.IsPersistent);
        e.ReissueCookie = true;
    }
}
```

The CreateSessionSecurityToken method takes a value for validFrom and validTo. If these two values are equal, it throws an ArgumentOutOfRange exception.

I ran into the problem because originally I was using sessionLifetime.Minutes (which was 0) rather than sessionLifetime.TotalMinutes (which was 100).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the same `KeyEffectiveTime`

```
e.SessionToken = sam.CreateSessionSecurityToken(
                     e.SessionToken.ClaimsPrincipal,
                     e.SessionToken.Context,
                     e.SessionToken.KeyEffectiveTime, 
                     e.SessionToken.KeyExpirationTime.AddHours(8), 
                     e.SessionToken.IsPersistent);
```